# Is there something similar to application_helper or application_controller for models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some functions that I use in every single model and I'd like to place these in something like **`ActiveRecord::Base`** so I won't have to name the same functions in all of my models.

I'm not even sure if something like this is according to best practices. Perhaps some Rails pros could show me something better.

Answer (score 3):

Write a module that contains your required methods, and `include MyModule` as needed.

You certainly can do as @derekerdmann suggested and create an abstract base class for your models:

```
class MyBaseModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  abstract_class = true

  def my_method(*args)
    #code goes here
  end
end

class MyModel < MyBaseModel

end
```

Just don't forget the `abstract_class = true` line or single table inheritance is assumed.

Personally, I prefer the mixin methodology, because if your models ever diverge in common functionality, you can group common functions into separate modules and `include` them as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your input. How do I use the mixin methodology?

Comment: Here's a pretty good basic tutorial: http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/15/mixins-in-ruby/
If you Google 'ruby mixins', you can find even more.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you can still use standard object-oriented practices in Rails.  Make a class that extends `ActiveRecord::Base` with all your common functionality, and then extend that class for each of your real ActiveRecord models.

Comment: Good OO design would be to only inherit if the classes have an "is a" relationship. For Ruby, I would recommend creating a Module and using `include`.

Comment: Why not create an answer showing this? I don't know how to use `include` in models.